# Can we say that binding energy is the work done by the strong nuclear force?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, work, binding-energy, strong-force

I know that the strong nuclear force is the force that holds the nucleus together by overcoming electromagnetic repulsion between protons. Binding energy is the minimum energy that is required to disassemble a nucleus into its constituent nucleons. In that case, can we say the work done by the strong nuclear force is the binding energy of the nucleus?

(I'm fairly new to particle physics).

Comment: Not really as work is a variable not useful in specialrelativity and quantum mechanics. have a look http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/nucbin.html

Comment: @annav "Binding energy indicates not only the potential energy associated with the nuclear strong force but also the electrostatic and weak forces involved in nuclei." -- Is this statement correct?

Comment: quoted from where? In general, at the quantum level descriptions of the nucleus it is the strong force against the electrostatic that define the potential that should be modeled  to be solved to define the energy levels that nucleons can occupy in a nucleus.  (the weak coupling is too small to affect ).The potentials are ad hoc, to fit the observations, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model  " When adding nucleons (protons or neutrons) to a nucleus, there are certain points where the binding energy of the next nucleon is significantly less than the last one. "  .

Comment: The binding energy curve is per nucleon, and average of the true binding of each.

Comment: So basically, strong force and the opposing electrostatic force is what defines the potential of the system. Thanks.